# UWP RequestedTheme is not consistent in ListView and ListViewItem

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app

My [NowPlayFullPage](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/NowPlayingFullPage.xaml.cs) has a [PlaylistControl](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/PlaylistControl.xaml.cs), which is basically a ListView.

```
<local:PlaylistControl
    x:Name="FullPlaylistControl"
    Margin="10,10,10,0"
    AllowReorder="True"
    AlternatingRowColor="False"
    Background="Transparent"
    IsNowPlaying="True"
    RequestedTheme="Dark" />
```

The `ItemTemplate` of the `PlaylistControl` is the following:

```
<local:PlaylistControlItem
    Data="{x:Bind}"
    DataContext="{x:Bind}"
    RequestedTheme="{Binding ElementName=PlaylistController, Path=RequestedTheme}"
    ShowAlbumText="{Binding ElementName=PlaylistController, Path=ShowAlbumText}" />
```

And in the `Loaded` event of the [`PlaylistControlItem`](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/PlaylistControlItem.xaml.cs), I called a function `SetTextColor`

```
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MediaHelper.SwitchMusicListeners.Add(this);
    SetTextColor(MediaHelper.CurrentMusic);
}

public void SetTextColor(Music music)
{
    if (Data == music)
    {
        TitleTextBlock.Foreground = ArtistTextButton.Foreground = AlbumTextButton.Foreground = DurationTextBlock.Foreground =
        LongArtistTextButton.Foreground = LongArtistAlbumPanelDot.Foreground = LongAlbumTextButton.Foreground = ColorHelper.HighlightBrush;
        TextColorChanged = true;
    }
    else if (TextColorChanged)
    {
        if (RequestedTheme == ElementTheme.Dark)
        {
            TitleTextBlock.Foreground = ColorHelper.WhiteBrush;
            ArtistTextButton.Foreground = AlbumTextButton.Foreground = DurationTextBlock.Foreground =
            LongArtistTextButton.Foreground = LongArtistAlbumPanelDot.Foreground = LongAlbumTextButton.Foreground = ColorHelper.GrayBrush;
        }
        else
        {
            TitleTextBlock.Foreground = ArtistTextButton.Foreground = AlbumTextButton.Foreground = DurationTextBlock.Foreground =
            LongArtistTextButton.Foreground = LongArtistAlbumPanelDot.Foreground = LongAlbumTextButton.Foreground = ColorHelper.BlackBrush;
        }
        TextColorChanged = false;
    }
}
```

My question is, why does the `RequestedTheme` in the `SetTextColor` called in the `Loaded` event have the value of `ElementTheme.Default` instead of `ElementTheme.Dark`? When does the `RequestTheme` of `PlaylistControlItem` hold the value of `Dark` so that my text color can be set correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advisably you should he handling this using ThemeResource's in XAML, not in code, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/themeresource-markup-extension

But to answer your question this is expected behaviour. `ElementTheme.Default` simply means the element has not had it's theme overridden and is using the default app theme. The other two values mean the element has specifically had it's theme overridden. `App.Current.RequestedTheme` gives the application's *actual* theme. `FrameworkElement.RequestedTheme` will always have a value of `Default` unless you explicitly set it to something else on that specific element. All of it's children will still have the value `Default`.

Note, you should compare against `ActualTheme`, not `RequestedTheme`, as a parent may have caused it to be using a different theme than the application if it's value is still `ElementTheme.Default`.

A method like below might help you to get a proper value of Light/Dark.

```
public static ElementTheme GetEffectiveTheme(FrameworkElement e)
{
    if (e.ActualTheme == ElementTheme.Default)
        return App.Current.RequestedTheme == ApplicationTheme.Dark ? ElementTheme.Dark : ElementTheme.Light;

    return e.ActualTheme;
}
```

But also, just use ThemeResources. They automatically re-evaluate on Theme change, no need for any code or event listeners.

Comment: Thank you so much! Using `ActualTheme` saves my life! I am actually using `ThemeResources` in xaml but I need my `TextBlock` to switch colors sometimes so I also need a programmatic way to do this.